# CORS DELETE fails with 403 status code

Tags: javascript, ajax, sinatra, rack, cors

I have developed a CORS REST server and some pages with some JS code that invoke its urls.

I decided to refactor the JS pages, and my DELETE ajax request to server now doesn't work anymore. Part of the refactor involves the URL that pass from `http://localhost/dev` to `http://dev.local`. I added the new url in the allowed origin for requests, in fact my `GET` routes still work without problems.

`DELETE` instead is not allowed now (403 on the preflight) and i don't understand where my mistake is.

Here the `OPTIONS` and `DELETE` dumps from dev perspective:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9292/users/101
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:DELETE
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9292
Origin:http://dev.local
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://dev.local/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://dev.local
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/plain
Server:thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
```

responds with a payload that contains "Forbidden". Here the `DELETE` req:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9292/users/101
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Request Headers
DELETE /users/101 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9292
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://dev.local
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://dev.local/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: fbsr_348362375211512=r2WOBYNXrmyP6lKJ7JVAnlU9gfLjela8jRSarGHvQ-M.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUURSRDhOckJ2YnI0MlFLTk5vblhiOGNVcjVXTFpHTDNMcVBjYl9PXzFqd3hKS0tlWFZ1cFVVMi03OXNxOU1BcjFGV2RxTzVtV0RSTllXbkxKcndUQmtZOFpMS3VmeWt0b05xU3ctVzdqNk4zVHBFQVZOM3ZlRzFKeW5lRWpiRkxSdXlPNHpGMDNVd255RFZqZ0xOdHQwMTJCUWVvb0NSR1ZSTVUtQkVhS1ZtaGtKZGdKck5RSDUwWHhQVW5wT1MyY0EiLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzNDY0MjUyMzgsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMDI5MDk2MTIzIn0; oauth2-token=; rack.session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiJFNTc3ZTMxZGZjNWUxYWNhZDU3NWUw%0ANjJkMDBkMDRiNmMxOWI0ODE5Yjk5YjMwMWI3YTMyOTM1ZjVmZWMyMGY1ZEki%0ADXRyYWNraW5nBjsARnsISSIUSFRUUF9VU0VSX0FHRU5UBjsARiItZGY1ZDgz%0AMzMyYTg4ZjBkNGY1ZGU0MGNjNzljMDhkNTUzZDJkMjkxNUkiGUhUVFBfQUND%0ARVBUX0VOQ09ESU5HBjsARiItZWQyYjNjYTkwYTRlNzIzNDAyMzY3YTFkMTdj%0AOGIyODM5Mjg0MjM5OEkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsARiItY2M5%0AZjZmZWM2NTJhNDI1OGJjNmQyOTI4NzA1MjE3OWFiMWUwZDE0N0kiB2lkBjsA%0ARmlqSSIObG9nZ2VkX2luBjsARlQ%3D%0A--c1a452275c10bd0ebe0e21fe7925d1fe7349c46f
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Type: text/plain
Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7CkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiJFNTc3ZTMxZGZjNWUxYWNhZDU3NWUw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%0AMTU0N2E2ZA%3D%3D%0A--578809491df1629d183c98a530ccbcf925000b6e; path=/; HttpOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://dev.local
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET, POST
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Vary: Origin
Connection: close
Server: thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
```

Any idea or suggestion to determine the problem?

Thanks, Dario.

Comment: The CORS portion of the request looks fine. The fact that you are receiving a 403 means that there is something going wrong at a deeper level than CORS. How are you handling authentication against http://dev.local? Are you sure the proper authentication credentials are being sent to the server?

Comment: In my JS I use jQuery using the $.ajax with the xhrFields:{withCredentials: true}, but I have tried also with the shim presented here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/. Server side I use `rack cors` gem.

Comment: Does your server need authentication? And if so, what kind of authentication is it using?

Comment: Nope, consider that all my ajax calls first of my refactor (that involve url changing) works. The server is the same. Anyway I'll take a look to `rack cors` gem trying to determine if is a "misconfiguration" problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a search and the advices by monsur (he helps me to realize that client side all is correct), I raised the rack log level to debug level and I've found an *"attack
prevented by Rack::Protection::RemoteToken"* notifing that the problem is a misconfiguration of `rack-protection`used by Sinatra.

By default, since the referrer is different, my app stumble in CSRF protection; disabling:

```
set :protection, :except => [:remote_token, :frame_options]
```

It works.